# Component not updated on dynamic rendring

Tags: react-native

I have to render a `touchablehighlight` based on some condition.Here is a part of render method:

```
render(){ 
     . . .

{  !this.state.isNewMsg?
      <View key={this.state.isNewMsg}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          <Text>
            . . .
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
   :

   <View>
   <TouchableHighlight>
     . . .
   </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
}
```

and my state is changed:

```
someMethod() {

   this.setState({isNewMsg:true});

}
```

But the component is not updated.What's wrong with the conditional rending? I have tried assigning the `touchablehighlight` Id's too and then changing the state with id values but no luck.

**UPDATE**

More code:

Render Method:

```
 render() {
      return ( 
   . . . 

{!this.state.isNewMsg?

    <View key={this.state.isNewMsg} style={{ flex:1, width:200, alignSelf:'center'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor = {'white'}
    onPress={this._seeMessage.bind(this)}
    disabled={this.state.dontShowMsg} >
    <Text style = {[styles.button,{color:this.state.buttonColor,
      backgroundColor:this.state.buttonBackgroundColor}]}>
            Messages
    </Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
   </View>
   :
   <View key={this.state.isNewMsg} style={{ flex:1, width:200, alignSelf:'center'}}>
   <TouchableHighlight
   underlayColor = {'white'}
   onPress={this._seeMessage.bind(this)}
   >
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('./newMsg.gif')}
      />
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
 }
 . . .
<otherComponents/>
 . . .
```

Method called on component mount:

```
getMessagesFireBase(){
  var id=this.state.uid;
  var that = this;
  Firebase.ref('/msg/' + this.state.uid).once('value').then(
  function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child){
    var key = child.key;
    var value = child.val();
    if(that.isObject(value) && value.isReply)
      {
        if(that.state.oldMsg!==value.reply)
        {
            try {
               AsyncStorage.setItem('oldMsg',value.reply);
               this.setState({isNewMsg:true}); //not updated
            } catch (error) {
              // Error saving data
            }
        }

        that.setState({userQuestion:value.umsg, //works fine
          userReply:value.reply,
          dontShowMsg:false,
          buttonColor:'white',
          buttonBackgroundColor:'rgba(128,0,0,0.3)'
        });
      }
});
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of context.

```
if(that.state.oldMsg!==value.reply)
    {
        try {
           AsyncStorage.setItem('oldMsg',value.reply);
           this.setState({isNewMsg:true}); //not updated. Because of THIS
           /* You even saved context into `that` variable.
              Forgot about it? Anyway change it to `that.setState()`
              and everything should be ok.
           */
        } catch (error) {
          // Error saving data
        }
    }
```

Comment: umm do you know some easy ways to commit suicide ?

Comment: Take it easy :) It's all because of JavaScript. Everybody has ever made such mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I need to configure it as it pops out too much spacing issues too.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to be valid code

```
someMethod() {
   someCallback(){
   this.setState({isNewMsg:true});
   }
}
```

It should be something like

```
someMethod() {
   this.setState({isNewMsg:true});
}
```

And to trigger it you would do

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.someMethod}>
...
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Can you show more code then? Is there a component boundary? Are you sure you aren't passing in the value is a prop and looking for `this.props.isNewMsg`? 

There isn't a lot to go on here with out an error message. If you could use the `Remote Debugger` option. Then put a breakpoint and just make sure it's getting called that would beneficial.

Comment: I have updated some more code if it helps.The component won't re-render even if I force updated it.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you use `bind(this)` in the constructor ?

Or use **ES6 arrow function**

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.someMethod()}>
...
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: I'm not firing any event `onPress` . The state happens to be updated on some other event and I'm sure that event is fired.

Comment: So your problem maybe `this` not right? 
Try it in log.

Comment: The method where i'm setting the state is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `someMethod`

```
someMethod = () => {
  this.setState({isNewMsg:true});
}
```

Now your method will have the correct `this` context to change your state!